# Understanding __getattribute__

Tags: python, python-2.7, attributes

```
class Shadow(object):
    pass

class Test(object):
    a = 1
    b = 2

    _shadow = Shadow()

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        try:
            return object.__getattribute__(self._shadow, name)
        except: print "not shadowed"
        return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
```

With the above piece of code I would like to implement the following behavior:

```
>>>t = Test()
>>>t.a
1
>>>t._shadow.a = 17
>>>t.a
17
>>>t.b
2
```

The code works, but it will print "not shadowed" M-times (until recursion depth is reached). The question is why, there shouldn't be any recursion involved, I'm calling `object.__getattribute__` and not `self.__getattribute__`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`__getattribute__` is called for **all** attribute access, including for `self._shadow`. But since you have `__getattribute__` overridden, `self._shadow` triggers an infinite recursion.

The only work-around for that is to use `object.__getattribute__`, or better, `super(Test, self).__getattribute__`, to retrieve the `_shadow` attribute:

```
class Test(object):
    a = 1
    b = 2

    _shadow = Shadow()

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        shadow = super(Test, self).__getattribute__('_shadow')
        try:
            return getattr(shadow, name)
        except AttributeError:
            print "not shadowed"
        return super(Test, self).__getattribute__(name)
```

There is no need to use `object.__getattribute__` for the attribute access on the shadow object. Don't use Pokemon-style exception handling (you don't want to catch them all); catch only the specific `AttributeError` exception here.

Demo:

```
>>> t = Test()
>>> t.a
not shadowed
1
>>> t._shadow.a = 42
not shadowed
>>> t.a
42
```

Note that here too, accessing `t._shadow` triggers the `'not shadowed'` message as it goes through the `__getattribute__` handler.

Comment: you still have a typo in the try block it's shadow, not _shadow

Comment: do you know why dir(t) doesn't show a and b? does dir take the dir of _shadow? probably. does dir simply take __locals__

Comment: @user1514631: because `t.__dict__` retrieves the attribute dictionary from `_shadow`; `dir(instance)` takes `instance.__dict__` to determine the list (plus `__members__`, `__methods__` and `__class__` if present).

Comment: What about just using `__getattr__`?

Comment: @ikaros45: That's only called for attributes that are not defined; e.g. `__getattr__` is called when `__getattribute__` couldn't find the attribute elsewhere first.

Comment: @ikaros45: that won't work if you want `_shadow` to *override* existing attributes.