# Why are there two magic methods to access object attributes in Python?

Tags: python, object, attributes, accessor

I'm studying Python's object attribute access patterns ([Descriptor HowTo Guide](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html) and [Data model docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__)). The thing I can't clearly understand is why did Guido provide both `__getattr__` and `__getattribute__` methods for objects? They both do exactly the same thing but are invoked differently.

For me this seems as if a badly designed class could be fixed by even worse design. I mean, if something needs refactoring, it should not be "glued" with magic methods being called with high or higher precedence.

The question is - why are there two similar methods if one would be perfectly enough?

I'm not referring to descriptors, which are something different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two methods serve *different* purposes.

`__getattribute__` is called for **all** attribute access. `__getattr__` is only called *by `__getattribute__`* if the latter failed to locate an attribute.

It is far easier to implement a correct `__getattr__` method than it is to implement a `__getattribute__` replacement. Sure, you can do without `__getattr__` in that scenario, but that also would make implementing the common use-case all the harder.

For example, in `__getattr__` you can easily access *other, existing* attributes on `self`; if you need `self.bar` to fulfil a dynamic attribute, then that's easy to do so. In `__getattribute__` you cannot access anything on `self` with normal attribute access, as that is all handled by `__getattribute__` methods; you'd end up in an infinite recursion if you tried. Instead, **all** attribute access within that method has to use `super(ClassName, self).__getattribute__(name)` calls.

Note that `__getattribute__` is *always* implemented; `object.__getattribute__` provides the default implementation. Use `__getattribute__` only if you need to intercept the default behaviour; say you need to override existing attributes in special circumstances, or override the normal [descriptor behaviour](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html). See [Understanding __getattribute__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22986546/understanding-getattribute) for an example where existing attribute access is being overridden.

Use `__getattr__` for everything else; e.g. dynamic attributes where those attributes do not already exist on the object. Say, you are providing a proxy class, where most attribute access is passed on to the wrapped object:

```
class Proxy(object):
    def __init__(self, wrapped):
        self._wrapped = wrapped

    def foo(self):
        return self._wrapped.foo() + 42

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self._wrapped, name)
```

Here `_wrapped` and `foo` are found directly on `Proxy()`, but if you tried to access `bar`, an attribute that does not exist on the `Proxy` class, `__getattr__` is called instead which translates that as attribute access on `self._wrapped`.

Comment: I really appreciate your explanation, but trust me, it's not easy, I don't get it yet. Can you provide a real-world example where this distinction could be made?

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz: I've expanded a little, linking to a different question / answer for the `__getattribute__` case.

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz: needing to override `__getattribute__` is rare, for the most part. This is why `__getattr__` exists, to make the common use case easy.